# How display multiple rows in a table with one row in another table as single row

Tags: php, mysql, select, sum, group-concat

I have two tables.
Table "user" contains user_id, user_name
Table "Transactions" contains user_id, transactions

Eg:

```
TABLE USER:
user_id, user_name
1, Ram
2, John
3, Rahim

TABLE Transactions
user_id, transactions
1,  500
1, 300
2, 250
1, 450
3, 100
1, 250
3, 50
```

I want to display the result as:

```
user_name, Total
Ram, 1500*
John, 250
Rahim, 150
```

- it is the sum of all transactions of that particular user

How can I do this?

Comment: My question has a mistake. My result should be: user_id, Total. (Not user_name, Total) Sorry for confuse you.

Comment: Post edited. Anyway I think you got the right answer.

Comment: Sorry again. Before rewriting my comment, I just hit "enter" key.  I need user_name, Total (eg: Ram, 1500). Please ignore my last comment. Once again sorry for my mistakes

Comment: Well, so the genesis answer is the right one.

Comment: Thanks a lot! stackoverflow.com ROCKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    u.user_name, 
    SUM(t.transactions) Total
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN transactions t ON t.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY t.user_id
```

I think you should use LEFT JOIN because it should select user's total (NULL) in any case, even if it's 0

Comment: Why the need of the join if all the data the user wants is in the same table?

Comment: It seems that, but as you can see, in his example, he put the user_id and not the user_name. I'm confused about it too.

Comment: @Aur yeah, your answer is good one if he wants user_id. We'll see

Comment: Thanks. I asked because your answer is good and was my first thought before I realize the example.

Comment: I know how to display fields from a single table. But I wrote my question mistakely. I need user_name, Total (eg: Ram, 1500).

Comment: so in that case @user my answer fits for you

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.user_id , SUM(t.transactions) AS total
FROM user AS u JOIN transactions AS t
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    sum(t.transactions) as total
FROM
    user u
    JOIN transactions t ON u.user_id = t.user_id
GROUP BY
    u.user_id
```